# Which model did Auto-Sklearn choose?

Tags: scikit-learn, auto-sklearn

I'm just getting started with auto-sklearn. I have implemented the below - it runs fine.

I'm not clear how I know which model & parameters it chose though?

Also, if it manages some of the preprocessing steps (e.g. imputing nulls & encoding), how do I then deploy the 'pipeline' including those steps?

Thanks a lot

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import autosklearn.classification

train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, output, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
model = autosklearn.classification.AutoSklearnClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(train_features, train_labels)
predictions = model.predict(test_features)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/manual.html#inspecting-the-results), there are `model.cv_results_` for comprehensive stats, and `show_models()` to print the final (ensemble) models.  Presumably you will just binarize the entire autosklearn object and deploy it, so that preprocessing still happens internally.  (In a quick example, the ensemble consists of many `SimpleClassificationPipeline` objects, which are wrappers around sklearn `Pipeline`s.)